# How to fix Android Studio error "compileDebugAidl"

Tags: java, android, aidl

i'm trying to use an AIDL in android studio but the JAVA classes won't recognize the AIDL (it says "cannot resolve") and i even hard coded the import line of the AIDL and it still doesn't recognize the AIDL, i tried to clean and rebuild the project multiple times but it doesn't work, it just gives me a "compileDebugAidl" error.

Here's the error i'm getting at first:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And after selecting the latest line in the build panel this is the error it's showing:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at
```

I've searched a solution for over 3 days on Google, YouTube and here and got nothing helpful and current..

I'd love to get some help with this issue, thank you :)

Comment: It looks to me like AIDL might be running but aborting because of some error, probably in your AIDL files.  Can you show the files?  Does it do the same thing from the CLI?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, i solved the problem, I tried to use the AIDL in the Java classes before cleaning and rebuilding the project, so Android Studio didn't have the chance to auto generate the AIDL's Java files so that was the problem, to solve that I just ashed all the places I was trying to use the AIDL then cleaned and rebuilt the project and then deleted the ashes and everything works now.. 
(By "Ashes" I mean to put the '//' before the lines of code so these lines won't run with the code)